# PHP get mp3 file path

Tags: php, curl, flash

I have been working on a project where I am required to get or extract the file path to the mp3 file from all music players on the web. As of now, I am focusing on soundcloud player. Is it possible to get the mp3 file path from soundcloud player? I am thinking to use php curl for this but not sure how.

I needed to create a universal code for the extraction so using the soundcloud API I think would not be a good solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

SoundCloud does not provide full mp3 paths for fhe files.
You need to use SoundCloud API (they have an example for PHP as well):

http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api#playing

Note, that there are only 128 kbps versions of MP3 files available.